# Durable Azure Function Integration Test dont run up

Tags: azure-functions, integration-testing, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to do some integrations test to my Az Func. I am using .Net 7, so I am not using a startup file, I just using a program.cs file:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .AddHttpJsonClientOptions(o => {
       ...
    }).Build();

host.Run();
```

The class of the endpoint is easy too:

```
    public static class Example
    {
        [Function(nameof(Example))]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> StartAsync(
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "patch", Route = "/{param1}/example")] HttpRequestData request,
            string param1, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
          ...
        }
    }
```

And this is the code that I have in my project test:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Text;

namespace Example
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FunctionTests
    {
        private TestServer _server;
        private HttpClient _client;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebJobs(builder => builder.AddHttp())
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    // Here you can add any service you need for your tests.
                });

            var serviceProvider = hostBuilder.Build().Services;
            _server = new TestServer(serviceProvider);
            _client = _server.CreateClient();
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
            _server.Dispose();
        }

        // Here you can add your integration tests.
        [Test]
        public async Task HttpTriggerTest()
        {
            // Arrange  
            var body = $@"
            {{
                ""property1"": property1,
                ""date"": ""2023-08-12"",
                }}
            }}";

            var requestContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, "param1/example")
            {
                Content = requestContent
            };

            // Act  
            var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

            // Assert  
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.AreEqual("Hello, world!", responseContent);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to execute the test, the Test Server dont work and I just receive the error:

```
Mensaje: 
OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : The server has not been started or no web application was configured.
```

I am really really lost in this ponit... I dont know how to fix this.

I would like to know where I am fail, or what I missed in order to get well configured my TestServer for testing Azure Functions.